# Change color of button when scrolled to target section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I finally figured out how to snap to a section on scroll and when clicking the buttons. The buttons change its color when clicked. Can you help me figure out how to change the button color when the page is scrolled? So when the screen is on section 1, the button 1 should be grey. If I scroll to section 2, the button 2 should be grey and other buttons should go back to black. Here's the code:

```
<header class="nav">
    <nav class="buttons">
        <div class="button-holder">
            <a class="buttons-a active" href="#panel1div">•</a>
            <a class="buttons-a" href="#panel2div">•</a>
            <a class="buttons-a" href="#panel3div">•</a>
            <a class="buttons-a" href="#panel4div">•</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<section id="paneldivs">
    <article id="panel1div" class="panel1 panels">
        <h1>Panel 1</h1>
    </article>

    <article id="panel2div" class="panel2 panels">
        <h1>Panel 2</h1>
    </article>

    <article id="panel3div" class="panel3 panels">
        <h1>Panel 3</h1>
    </article>
    <article id="panel4div" class="panel4 panels">
        <h1>Panel 4</h1>
    </article>
</section>
```

CSS

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: none;
}

body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

h1 {
    padding: 50vh 0;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.buttons {
    width: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.button-holder {
    height: 100vh;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.buttons a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #000;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}

a.active {
    color: #999;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.panels {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0 );
    transform: translateZ( 0 );
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.panel1 {
    background: #ccc;
}

.panel2 {
    background: #ff0;
}

.panel3 {
    background: #ddd;
}

.panel4 {
    background: #0ff;
}
</style>
```

Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".buttons-a").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
})
});
// handle links with @href started with '#' only
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
    // target element id
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    // target element
    var $id = $(id);
    if ($id.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    // prevent standard hash navigation (avoid blinking in IE)
    e.preventDefault();

    // top position relative to the document
    var pos = $id.offset().top;

    // animated top scrolling
    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos});
});
var scrolling = false;

$(document).on("wheel mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e) {
  if (!scrolling) {
  var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (e.type === "mousewheel" || e.type === "wheel") {
    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0) {
      down = true;
    } else {
      down = false;
    }
  } else if (e.type === "DOMMouseScroll") {
    if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
      down = true;
    } else {
      down = false;
    }
  } else if (e.type === "keyup") {
          var keycode = e.originalEvent.keyCode;
          if (keycode === 40 || keycode === 32 || keycode === 34) { //down, space, pgdwn
            down = true;
          } else if (keycode === 38 || keycode === 33) { //up, pgup
            down = false;
          } else if (keycode === 35) { //end
            down = 2;
          } else if (keycode === 36) { //home
            down = 3;
          } else {
            return;
          }
        } else {
    return;
  }
  var destination = scroll;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  if (down && scroll !== h * 3) {
    destination = Math.floor((destination + h) / h) * h;
  } else if (!down && scroll !== 0) {
    destination = Math.ceil((destination - h) / h) * h;
  } else {
    return;
  }
    scrolling = true;
  $("html, body").stop().animate({
    scrollTop: destination
  }, function() {
    scrolling = false;
  });
  }
})
</script>
```

Thanks...

Comment: `òffsetTop` tells you where the top-left side of an element is placed on the DOM, `document.documentElement.scrollTop` tells you where your scroll is currently. `if(document.getElementById('panel2div').offsetTop > document.documentElement.scrollTop){ document.querySelector('a[href="#panel2div"]').style.color = "orange"; }`

Comment: @Pavlo can you provide me the exact jquery code to place? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the window "scroll location" of an element with `.scrollHeight`, which is the top-most point of that element. So the window "scroll top" of the element would be `.scrollHeight`, and the window "scroll bottom" of the element would be `.scrollHeight + (height of element)`.

EDIT: updating with a jsfiddle instead

https://jsfiddle.net/wby54h1e/39/

Comment: I should also add some additional clarification that in browsers, the `scrollHeight` *increases* as you go down the page, which can be rather confusing.

Comment: how can I then add the class to the button?

Comment: Where I put the comment "// do something", add the class here $('#myBtn').addClass('myClass');

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wby54h1e/39/ this is great! However, all other sections from the top turns red and scrolling upwards turns the section into blue. The only one that should change is the one on focus in the screen.